# Binding a click event with a element which has onClick attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, bind

I want to bind a click event with the element:

```
$('a').click(function(){ btn_submit_pressed=false; });
```

Now, I want to bind this click event with an element which has onClick attribute values, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="win_zip('fwrite', 'ext3_00', 'ext3_01', 'ext3_02', 'ext3_03');"> 
  <img width="91" height="20" src="<?=$board_skin_path?>/ez.img/post_search_btn.gif" border=0 align=absmiddle> 
</a>
```

How can I select all the elements which have values in onClick attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work using an attribute selector:

```
$('a[onclick]').on('click', function(){ ... });
```

*edit: use (`.bind()` instead of `.on()`) for jQuery < 1.7*

Comment: @OpenCode, just a quick note to mention that the `on` is available since jQuery 1.7 and @Calderan, +1

Comment: @OpenCode, and if you want to avoid the inline onclick to happen. You might want to use `removeAttr("onclick")` since it will most likely trigger before the jQuery click event.

Comment: @Calderan, WOW great. jquery select is some mess for me.